# Python: Conditional Row Values From a New Column Using dictionary, function, and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe:

```
id
id1
id2
id3
id8
id9
```

I want to add a new column `new` with conditional row values as follows:

If a row from `id` == `id1`, then the new row is `id1 is cat 1`

If a row from `id` == `id2`, then the new row is `id2 is cat 2`

If a row from `id` == `id3`, then the new row is `id3 is cat 3`

else, `idx is cat 0`, where x is the id that is not one of `id1`, `id2`, or `id3`

This is what I tried so far. I think the solution should be to wrap the for loop inside a function and use that function with `apply` and/or `lambda`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id8', 'id9']
}) 
df

dict = {'id1': '1', 'id2': '2', 'id3': '3'}

for k, val in dict.items():
    if k == "id1" or k == "id2" or k == "id3" in df['state']:
        print(str(k) + " is cat " + str(val))
    else:
        print(str(k) + " is cat 0")
```

Desired result:

```
id     new
id1   id1 is cat 1
id2   id2 is cat 2
id3   id3 is cat 3 
id8   id8 is cat 0
id9   id9 is cat 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple dictionary lookup.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id8', 'id9']
}) 

subst = {'id1': '1', 'id2': '2', 'id3': '3'}

def fix(row):
    val = subst.get(row['id'],0)
    return f"{row['id']} is cat {val}"

df['new'] = df.apply(fix,axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id          new
0  id1  id1 is cat 1
1  id2  id2 is cat 2
2  id3  id3 is cat 3
3  id8  id8 is cat 0
4  id9  id9 is cat 0
```

Comment: For the values in the new column, I want the grab the row values from the id column i.e., id1, id2, id3, id8, and i9 instead of all being id

Comment: OK, but that's a little redundant, since you already have the id column.

Answer (score 1):

You can get number and save in `m` then use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and if number `m.isin(['1','2','3'])` use number of `m` else use `0`.

```
import numpy as np
m = df['id'].str[2:]
tf = m.isin(['1','2','3'])
df['new'] = np.where(tf, 
                     df['id'] + " is cat " + m , 
                     df['id'] + " is cat 0")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id           new
0  id1  id1 is cat 1
1  id2  id2 is cat 2
2  id3  id3 is cat 3
3  id8  id8 is cat 0
4  id9  id9 is cat 0
```